# Did Swami Vivekananda idealize Ekalavya for modern students?

Tags: mahabharata, vivekananda

Ekalavya learnt many things by just considering Drona as his teacher. But he is on the side of Adharma.

Many websites are claiming that Swami Vivekananda told the following lines

> Ekalavya, an ideal for modern students, learnt archery without any external help. By self-effort and faith in one’s power, longing for knowledge and by self-reliance, one can do miracles.

Was it really said by him?

Comment: i do not know.But what if he was on the side of adharma? One can learn any good thing from anyone and he is definitely respectable as a student

Comment: @Pratimaputra but there is an issue in the case of Ekavalvya, he didn't learn directly from a guru and any such education will not shine as per scriptures. I'm thinking I'm that aspect.

Comment: He kept Drona's idol and worshipped with full devotion.That shd be enough i think

Comment: @Pratimaputra A student should learn from face to face conversation of Guru... I heard from preachings...

Comment: Ramana Maharshi had no Guru but such a Vedantin is born very rarely

Comment: @Pratimaputra ha, he was jivanmukta... Different from this...

Comment: Yes Mahashi was an Incarnation.But one who can offer own thumb to Guru being an archer of that stature just being asked for by Guru is also very very great person.